# install mongodb 5.0.2 on fedora 34

Tags: mongodb, installation, nosql, fedora

I am trying to install mongo on fedora 34.

I have the yum config:

```
/etc/yum.repo.d/mongodb-org-5.0.repo
```

with the text

```
[mongodb-org]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/8/mongodb-org/5.0/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc
```

To install mongo I run

```
sudo yum install -y mongodb-org
```

It fails with the following:

```
Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - package mongodb-org-5.0.0-1.el8.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-tools, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-5.0.2-1.el8.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-tools, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-tools-5.0.0-1.el8.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database-tools-extra, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-tools-5.0.2-1.el8.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database-tools-extra, but none of the providers can be installed
  - nothing provides /usr/libexec/platform-python needed by mongodb-org-database-tools-extra-5.0.0-1.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides /usr/libexec/platform-python needed by mongodb-org-database-tools-extra-5.0.2-1.el8.x86_64
```

Please help me with the installation steps.
I am not able to install even after following the official mongo installation guide

Comment: Did you try to install `mongodb-org-tools` first?

Comment: No. Any steps??? guide or something?? I didnt find anything of that sort in the officeial install guide.

Comment: Download from https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools?tck=docs_databasetools and install.

Answer (score 1):

try to install the server, shell and tools separately

```
sudo dnf install mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-database-tools mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-mongosh
```

[Related issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-58870)